# Couldn't download using selenium Chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

Im trying to change the download directory in chrome using prefs method, though the directory changes, download fails stating an error.This is the below code Ive used in python.

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
prefs = {'download.default_directory': selected_folder,
         'savefile.default_directory': selected_folder
        }
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
chrome_options.add_argument("--enable-logging")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service,options=chrome_options)
```

Actually it clicks a button to download from chrome set using find element by id.

I tried the above code, but the download fails

Comment: and the error was ?

Comment: I get "something went wrong" and downloads are not happening to the changed target folder, but when the default download directory is not changed download goes through